# how to call c functions from client dynamic library in Java

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface, native, swig

I am new to native code programming in java. i have client dll where they have exposed apis and also given api document.I want to use them in java.
I have written some code to load native library using system.loadLibrary and declared few native methods and able to call them successfully.
But they have some callback methods as well and few data structures that needs to be passed. I have written simlar classes in Java seeing their api. But it is not working.

i am confused about JNI or JNa uses. do I need to use them and create any  header files as I already native methods are implmented.
i suppose jni to be used only when we need to develop some part of code in other language like c c++.
Creating header files and then implementing and creating dll. But thats already with me.

Whats the way to easily write those typedef in java??

and is my understanding correct that i dont need jni or jna for this?

Comment: You have provide `JNI` based adapter for the code inside library. To some extent, `JNA` can make your life easier, however, I bet you will eventually face the structures that can not be easily mapped `Java <-> C/C++`. I suggest to write `JNI` bridge library that will adapt structures back and forth: http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-021/

Comment: Client has provided jni interface i.e. .i files and wrapper classes and dlls , how to use them?

Comment: If you have `JNI` interface, all you have to do is to load library and call functions from the shared library. Take a look at very first sample here: http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-001/ - in your case, it would be best to look for Windows based tutorial :(

Comment: thanks Oo.oO, I am directly calling functions,  My understanding is provided dll is enriched with JNI interface that's why I am able to call functions directly in java. Is it correct?